# SensorManager only working on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors, sensormanager

I have the following code to get the x and y angle of my device and it is working fine on my phone, but not my tablet (Samsung galaxy tab e). I was wondering if anyone had any idea as to what could be causing it to work on one device but not another.

I did also ensure that screen rotation was enabled on both. My assumption is that the tablet is lacking a sensor, and what I'm looking for most is a workaround. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Source code:

```
double yAngle;
double xAngle;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),RATE);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] rotationMatrix;
    rotationMatrix = new float[16];
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values);
    determineOrientation(rotationMatrix);
    lblY.setText(String.format("%.1f", yAngle));
    lblX.setText(String.format("%.1f", xAngle));

}

private void determineOrientation(float[] rotationMatrix){
    //CREATING FLOAT ARRAY OF ORIENTATION VALUES
    float [] orientationValues = new float[3];
    SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationValues);
    yAngle = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[2]);
    xAngle = Math.toDegrees(orientationValues[1]);
}
```

Comment: `sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)` returns `null` when the sensor is not supported by the device. You can log its value to see whether it returns `null` in the tablet or not ?

Comment: It does indeed return null on the tablet. Would you know if there are other sensors that can be used? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adb shell pm list features` to check all sensors and other features supported.